# How to prevent FrameworkBundle assets being copied with `console assets:install` in Symfony3?

Tags: php, assets, symfony

*I am new to Symfony, creating my first project with Symfony3.
I wanted to make as much as possible "in the line" with [mainstream instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html).*

The problem I am trying to solve now is related with `console assets:install` CLI command: I **do not want** this command to copy `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/public/*` files to `web/bundles/framework` directory (they're just some misc files, such as Symfony logo).

I have looked for some sort of "exclusion" mechanism for `AssetsHelper`, but found nothing. I am aware that deleting `FameworkBundle` is not the way to go.

This might be also related with Symfony2.

Comment: Why do you exactly need it? It could be not bad idea for production enviroment but it's really stupid for development.

Comment: For production it could be the easiest way for hackers to detect that my website is running on Symfony, possibly detect even it's version. This could be 1st step to make a hacking attempt when some vulnerabilities of this particular version will be publicly known. I do not need that stuff in development version - why would I?

Comment: No, you wouldn't but you didn't write for what purpose you need it. I think you should delete this folder as a part of your deployment process. There are at least two more files that you want in development but not in production - `web/app_dev.php`, 'web/config.php'. [https://www.blablacar.de/bundles/framework/images/logo_symfony.png](https://www.blablacar.de/bundles/framework/images/logo_symfony.png) :-).

Comment: Hahaha, there you go! :D